# Slow Web Service with Async/Await

Tags: c#, web-services, azure, asynchronous

I have a very slow response time on my webservice, it's the first time i am using the Async/await option but not sure if it's correct. If i query the tables directly it would only take me about 3sec. but now it takes much longer.

What i would like to do is to find out what program is activated (visisble to the user) and in the first step just load the ProgramCode, the ReleaseDate and from the ProgramMetadata Table get the ProgramName (incl: the series option that does some combining) the rest can load after. Is this actually possible and if so, what changes do i need to make to accomplish this? I attached the webservice code:

```
[Route("Programs/{id_activation_state}")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetProgramByActivationState(int id_activation_state)
    {
        List<Program> ListPrograms = new List<Program>();

        foreach (var item in await db.Program.Where(p => p.id_program_activationState == id_activation_state).OrderBy(pg => pg.ProgramCode).ToListAsync())
        {
            Program programReturned = new Program();
            programReturned.id_program = item.id_program;
            programReturned.ReleaseDate = item.ReleaseDate;
            programReturned.ProgramCode = item.ProgramCode;
            programReturned.Duration = item.Duration;
            programReturned.ImdbCode = item.ImdbCode;
            programReturned.id_program_rating = item.id_program_rating;
            programReturned.id_program_activationState = item.id_program_activationState;
            programReturned.DefaultLanguage = item.DefaultLanguage;
            programReturned.ProgramType = item.ProgramType;
            programReturned.ListingGenre = item.ListingGenre;
            programReturned.ListingGenre1 = item.ListingGenre1;
            programReturned.ListingGenre2 = item.ListingGenre2;


            if (item.ProgramMetadata.Count > 0)
            {
                ProgramMetadata PM = new ProgramMetadata();
                PM = item.ProgramMetadata.Where(pm => pm.id_language == item.DefaultLanguage).FirstOrDefault();
                PM.ProgramActivationState = null;
                if (item.ProgramType == 3)
                {
                    var query = from ps in db.ProgramSerie
                                join pss in db.ProgramSerieSeason on ps.id_program_serie equals pss.id_program_serie
                                join pse in db.ProgramSerieEpisode on pss.id_program_serie_season equals pse.id_program_season
                                where pse.id_program == item.id_program
                                select new
                                {
                                    SerieName = ps.SerieName,
                                    Season = pss.SeasonNumber,
                                    Episode = pse.EpisodeNumber
                                };

                    if (query.Count() > 0)
                        PM.ProgramName = query.First().SerieName.Trim() + ": " + PM.ProgramName.Trim() + ", S" + query.First().Season + "E" + query.First().Episode;


                }

                programReturned.ProgramMetadata.Add(PM);
            }
            ListPrograms.Add(programReturned);
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Program = ListPrograms });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Await and Async run the code not parallel it only does not block the main thread. So that the UI can draw. But in a controller need other things. You could try the Parallel.For...
[MSDN Parallel for](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx)

But I think you should rethink about your Architecture. The call is blocked until the query ends. Better would be you send the request and leaves the controller method. In a background thread you run the query and at the end send over signalR the answer...